# In MDI Child Form Tool Tip Not Getting Displayed

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, mdi, mdichild

I am developing an  desktop windows application, which have multiple windows forms.

The initial version of the application was such that one form will be called by another  form.

But due to these multiple forms opening, I created a parent form and set it as MDI container  and made all other forms to be it's child and displayed in the parent form. But the tool tip which was properly displayed earlier (when one form called from another) is not displaying now.

In `Form1` i am using this:

```
Form2 obj=new Form2();
obj.MdiParent=this;
obj.show();
```

which will show the `Form2` in `Form1` where `Form1` is a MDIContainer.

The tool tips in Form1(MDI Container) is displayed properly ,but tool tips in Form2(MDI Child) not showing.

If anyone knows the solution for this problem please help, I really got stuck in this problem.

Comment: Please give _much more_ information on your problem. Which language are you using? Post some example code.

Comment: Hi Ranon ,  i am using c# to code the application. Sample code will be like following , In Form1 i am using this    Form2 obj=new Form2();  obj.MdiParent=this; obj.show() which will show the Form2 in Form1 where Form1 is MDIContainer

Comment: @mid This is not a forum. Be sure to read the [faq] and in the future, instead of posting a comment to add info, edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above problem solved for me , when i moved a control in  MDI Container to an area where child form is shown.